# Android / Nexus 7 throwing IOException for Geocoder.getFromLocationName()

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use Geocoder.getFromLocationName() and although the same search string works fine on these actual devices:

- Nexus 1 (2.3.6)
- Samsung Galaxy SIII (4.0.4)
- Galaxy Nexus (4.1.1)

on my Nexus 7 (4.1.1), the method throws a "Service not available" IOException

Here is the simplified code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
List<Address> addressFromSearch = geocoder.getFromLocationName("10918", 1);
```

I've also tried each device using mobile data and wifi-only and they all work fine. So far the only device/OS that does not work is the Nexus 7. I've also checked Geocoder.isPresent() -- and it returns true.

Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

After the OTA-Update for Galaxy Nexus to 4.1.2 this problem is solved finally. It was a bug regarding the Android version 4.1.1

Comment: Hi Martin -- Thanks for this. While it initially seemed to be related to 4.1.1, we launched the app last week and are seeing 10-15% of our Geocoder calls falling back to the Google Map API (this is the behavior when the Geocoder fails to return an address). Are you sure it was only on 4.1.1 and not a backend issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with my Galaxy SIII 4G, which runs on version 4.1.1.  (Exception Error message is "Service not Available", and Geocoder's isPresent function returns true.  Here is a link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009#makechanges if you want to upvote the issue....

Comment: Hi bkurzius, you're welcome. I tested this strange behaviour on three different devices. On an old smartphone, running 2.3.3, then on my Galaxy Tab, running 3.1 and on my Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1. I only expected this issue on the Android version 4.1.1 after I've updated to the newer version 4.1.2 for the Galaxy Nexus, the problem was finally solved by itself. So I am 99% sure, it was a 4.1.1 bug. 

Your 10-15% Geocoder fall backs are regarding only the 4.1.1 version of Android?

Comment: The Galaxy S3 is currently running Android 4.1.1. These are quite many devices. Unbelievable!

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue on samsung galaxy tab 2 android 4.0.4, I'm going to see if theres an update but definitely I'm up voting the issue.

Looks like there is a work around for my device!

If you reboot your machine on the samsung galaxy tab 2...it actually starts working!...thats what I call a work around!